# Install Microsoft SQL express database on Windows XP Home SP3?

Tags: sql-server, windows-xp

I am trying to install Microsoft SQL express on a Windows XP SP3 Home Edition machine. But it does not satisfy the requirements. Is there a way to remove SP3 from my machine and revert to SP2? Microsoft suggests that SQL Express will work Windows XP Home Edition SP2. Ideas/suggestions?

Comment: What? (15 chars)

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall MSXML6 SP2, by using Windows Installer Cleanup Utility which can be downloaded from http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/9/d/e9d80355-7ab4-45b8-80e8-983a48d5e1bd/msicuu2.exe. Then install SQL Server Express edition just like usual.

Comment: MSICUU is what you need; unfortunately, because some people can't be trusted to not blow up their PC when given a tool like MSICUU ... MS has removed it; officially, you can't download it from them any longer.